# air flex windowed application rotation

Tags: apache-flex, air, rotation, effects

We have a air/flex app that we want to add an effect to.  Basically we want to rotate the whole window when a particular button is clicked.  Similar to say how, the clock widget behaves in mac os dashboard when you click the 'i' button, the whole widget rotates.
I'm wondering if this sort of thing is possible in air/flex 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use Papervision3D to do this.

http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/

There are also some pre-built Flex effects that leverage PV3D available here:

http://www.tink.ws/blog/papervision3d-effects-for-flex-source/

You can use Tink's "Flip" effect just like you would any other built-in Flex effect.